# Repeatedly appended URLs after RewriteRule in .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, browser, url-rewriting

This is my first time re-writing urls to be SEO friendly.

Here's my htaccess rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ratings/ ratings.php
RewriteRule regions/ regionlist.php
RewriteRule mobile/ mobile.php
```

For some reason, when I click the same link twice, the url will append itself in the address bar. Heres a gif image showing this happening:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5hqA.gif]

Is this bad? If it is, does anyone know what's wrong ?

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks everyone

Comment: How you create your url? Write the php/html of the url creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your RewriteRules to this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ $1.php
```

and make sure that your links to be like this:

```
<a href="/ratings">ratings</a>
```

but if you need specific rewrites change the location of slash

```
RewriteRule /ratings ratings.php
RewriteRule /regions regionlist.php
RewriteRule /mobile mobile.php
```

Comment: Problem solved, thanks :D Just wondering though, should I create another rule if there isnt a '/' after the url, e.g http://localhost/food/ratings/ and http://localhost/food/ratings ? as they don't both point to the same place :/

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not the htaccess which couses trouble here... IMO you take current URL and append clicked item's name. Create the URL from scratch instead.

Comment: Turns out it was that I was just missing a '/' from my href attribute in the html, thanks mate :D

Answer (score 0):

if you want the rewrite to always be based off the root directory you may want to write your rules with a preceeding "/"(slash)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /ratings ratings.php
RewriteRule /regions regionlist.php
RewriteRule /mobile mobile.php
```

This should force the rewrite rule to append this to the root url.

Answer (score -2):

Use redirect:

```
redirect 301 /ratings /ratings.php
```

Comment: Why should they expose their internal page structure?

Comment: I don't see a problem with it, but some might

Comment: Someone like the founders of the Web? http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html :)

Comment: I guess humble pie is in order then for me! :)